While using $TBS->MergeBlock, the option ope=tbs:num seem to not work
I wrote a wrapper class around TinyButStrong / OpenTBS to generate Excel documents.
The result is fine (thank you Skrol29!), but on blocks, I am unable to generate numbers recognized as such. In Excel, it produces warnings "Number stored in the form of text".
If I add ;ope:tbs_num to the cell (example : [a.quantity;ope=tbs:num], the MergeBlock operation will produce an empty cell.
However, it works on single merges, outside blocks.
The code extract looks like that.
    // Load line data in a specific table
    foreach ($this->xml->lines as $lines) {        
        foreach ($lines->attributes() as $x => $y) {
            $lineattrib[$x] = $y;
        }
        $this->showmsg ('<br>Lines... <br><br>');
        $linekey = $lineattrib['linekey'];
        $this->showmsg ("<br>merging block -$linekey- <br>");
        $rows = array();
        foreach ($lines->children() as $child) {    
            $row = array();
            foreach ($child->attributes() as $a => $b) {
                $row[$a] = '';
                if (is_object($b)) {
                    $value = $b->__toString();
                    $row[$a] = $value;
                }                
            } 
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        
        // utf8_encode because 'a' is not utf8_encode('a'), inside xlsx file
        $TBS->MergeBlock(utf8_encode($linekey), $rows);
    }       

Some rows provided look like this : (htmlEcho is a function based on print_r)
htmlEcho var: row
Array
(
[rowid] => 1
[itemid] => KJ3S2248K
[itemname] => Name of this item
[quantity] => 2,5
[unit] => PCE
[price] => 100,00
)
    
htmlEcho var: row
Array
(
[rowid] => 2
[itemid] => KJ3S2248J
[itemname] => Nom de cet article
[quantity] => 3.5
[unit] => PCE
[price] => 80,00
)

In this example, two different attemps were made with the comma format.
NOTE : tbs_class.php is in version 3.15.0  and tbs_plugin_opentbs is in version 1.11.1
EDIT : tbs_plugin_opentbs updated to version 1.12.1, no change

You have to be sure that the merged field is actually a numeric (a string representing a numeric is supported). Can you provide a sample of  the variable $rows you try to merges and which includes the quantity field ?

Hi @Skrol29 I edited the question to provide two sample rows.

Hi @b2vincent, it's difficult to see what is not good.
Can you first try with the last OpenTBS version (1.12.1) ?
Then try to check the behavior when you replace ope=tbs:num with xope=tbs:num. This should avoid the cell transformation and display the value as a text.
Then also try to force the $rows variable just before the $TBS->MergeBlock(). Thy with numerical values like  $rows['quantity'] = 3.5;. Then with string values that are number, like $rows['quantity'] = '3.5'; .
If this does not help to see what is not good, you can send to me a snippet of the template.

Hi @Skrol29, I changed OpenTBS to version 1.12.1 and tried with xope=tbs:num to see; also tried to force of $row['quantity'] to numerical values or string values which are numbers.
I think I am on the way to the solution. $row['quantity'] must be set to numerical value like 3.5 or to the equivalent PHP string '3.5' AND the cell template set with ;ope=tbs:num AND the cell format to Number and absolutly no whitespace in the matching cell of the template.

Hi, is it solved ?

Yes, it's resolved; there was something incorrect, I think, in my template. The strict conformity to the specifications made it work. Thank you for your help.
